# (QWebView) QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Tags: c++, qt

Just trying to make a simple web viewer app so I can view a webpage in a widget and I am getting the error:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

I feel like this is a problem with the webkit? I am statically linking this project.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKit>
#include "Windows.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView(parent);
         view->load(QUrl("http://google.com/"));
         view->show();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui webkit network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = webkittest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

header file

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QtPlugin>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QtWebKit>

class QAction;
 class QCheckBox;
 class QComboBox;
 class QGroupBox;
 class QLabel;
 class QLineEdit;
 class QMenu;
 class QPushButton;
 class QSpinBox;
 class QTextEdit;


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
     //void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
     //void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:


private slots:
        //void onSslErrors(QNetworkReply* reply, const QList<QSslError> &errors);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebView* m_pWebView;

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Any ideas what could be causing that?

Comment: It's also being compiled in release mode as that is how I configured Qt.

Comment: Why do you call "view->show();" in the constructor of the Mainwindow? I think you have to put the webviewer widget into the mainwindow. You could add a layout to the mainwindow and add the webviewer to the layout, OR you simply set the webviewer to the centralwidget of the mainwindow, but you don't call the show() method of it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by installing the latest version of Qt framework and dynamically linking webkit as they have disable static linking.